# google assistant saying "sorry, it looks like the camera doesn't support streaming to remote screens"

Tags: ip-camera, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I am trying to integrate my camera with google assistant for streaming, after syncing, and I requested google assistant "play *hall camera* on *office TV*" so I can get execute command to my webhook, but I am not receiving any execute request.it's saying "sorry, it looks like the hall camera doesn't support streaming to remote screens"

below is the sync response

```JSON
{
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "USER3103",
        "devices": [
            {
                "traits": [
                    "action.devices.traits.CameraStream"
                ],
                "willReportState": false,
                "name": {
                    "name": "hall camera"
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "cameraStreamNeedAuthToken": true,
                    "cameraStreamSupportedProtocols": [
                        "webrtc"
                    ],
                    "cameraStreamNeedDrmEncryption": false
                },
                "id": "210XXXXXXXX",
                "type": "action.devices.types.CAMERA",
                "deviceInfo": {
                    "swVersion": "0.0.0",
                    "model": "11010",
                    "manufacturer": "WIFICAMERA",
                    "hwVersion": "HD_1.2.3"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote screens doesn't support `webrtc` protocol like Chromecast

in the above case, `cameraStreamSupportedProtocols`  is only webrtc that's why it's saying

```
"Sorry, it looks like the camera doesn't support streaming to remote screens"
```

other protocols will work fine like `hls`,`progressive_mp4` etc...