# What equipment is supported action.devices.traits.CameraStream base on webRTC?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I have implemented CameraStream base on webRTC. It doesn't work on Chromecast and says "Sorry ,it looks like the cameraName doesn't support streaming to remote screens."
But it works fine on Google nest Hub.

I'd like to know which equipment is supported under webRTC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757307/google-assistant-saying-sorry-it-looks-like-the-camera-doesnt-support-streami

Comment: the possible reason could be the same. that you are cameraStreamSupportedProtocols is only webrtc.

Comment: please go through this question and answer as you already implemented in nest hub.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266937/how-to-integrate-smart-home-camerastream-with-aws-kinesis-video-streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the chromecast devices do not support WebRTC protocol for camera streaming. However we are working to expand the supported protocols on our devices. You can post a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148

New generation Google Nest Hub family of devices should provide support for WebRTC streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Chromecast devices don't support webRTC protocol. If you want to use the [cameraStream](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream) trait with your devices and stream to a ChromeCast device, you can use these [protocols](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/camerastream#streaming%20protocols). Teams are looking into expanding the chromecast capabilities.